# Get skipped file names into Excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that goes through a large directory of Excel files and performs a task (filters files and put results into new sheet within the active workbook). The VBA skips files that are unable to load (file may be unreadable):

```
Sub Ladiesman191()
'includes filling down

Dim wb As Workbook, fileNames As Object, errCheck As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wks As Worksheet, wksSummary As Worksheet
    Dim y As Range, intRow As Long, i As Integer
    Dim r As Range, lr As Long, myrg As Range, z As Range
    Dim boolWritten As Boolean, lngNextRow As Long
    Dim intColNode As Integer, intColScenario As Integer
    Dim intColNext As Integer, lngStartRow As Long

    Dim lngLastNode As Long, lngLastScen As Long

     ' Turn off screen updating and automatic calculation
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

     ' Create a new worksheet, if required
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wksSummary = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unique data")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wksSummary Is Nothing Then
        Set wksSummary = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
        wksSummary.Name = "Unique data"
    End If

     ' Set the initial output range, and assign column headers
    With wksSummary
        Set y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Set r = y.Offset(0, 1)
        Set z = y.Offset(0, -2)
        lngStartRow = y.Row
        .Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("File Name", "Sheet Name", "Node Name", "Scenario Name")
    End With

'get user input for files to search
Set fileNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
errCheck = UserInput.FileDialogDictionary(fileNames)
If errCheck Then
   Exit Sub
End If
'''
For Each Key In fileNames 'loop through the dictionary




On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileNames(Key))
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wb = Nothing    ' or set a boolean error flag
End If
On Error GoTo 0    ' or your custom error handler

If wb Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Error when loading " & fileNames(Key)
Else
    Debug.Print "Successfully loaded " & fileNames(Key)
    wb.Application.Visible = False 'make it not visible
    ' more working with wb



 ' Check each sheet in turn
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
             ' Only action the sheet if it's not the 'Unique data' sheet
            If .Name <> wksSummary.Name Then
                boolWritten = False

                 ' Find the Scenario column
                intColScenario = 0
                On Error Resume Next
                intColScenario = WorksheetFunction.Match("scenarioName", .Rows(1), 0)
                On Error GoTo 0

                If intColScenario > 0 Then
                     ' Only action if there is data in column E
                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(intColScenario)) > 1 Then
                         ' Find the next free column, in which the extract formula will be placed
                        intColNext = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

                         ' Assign formulas to the next free column to identify the scenario name to the left of the first _ character
                        .Cells(1, intColNext).Value = "Test"
                        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, intColScenario).End(xlUp).Row
                        Set myrg = .Range(.Cells(2, intColNext), .Cells(lr, intColNext))
                        With myrg
                            .ClearContents
                            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(LEFT(RC" & intColScenario & ",FIND(INDEX({""+"",""-"",""_"",""$"",""%""},1,MATCH(1,--(ISNUMBER(FIND({""+"",""-"",""_"",""$"",""%""},RC" & _
                            intColScenario & "))),0)), RC" & intColScenario & ")-1), RC" & intColScenario & ")"
                            .Value = .Value
                        End With

                         ' Copy unique values from the formula column to the 'Unique data' sheet, and write sheet & file details
                        .Range(.Cells(1, intColNext), .Cells(lr, intColNext)).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , r, True
                        r.Offset(0, -2).Value = ws.Name
                        r.Offset(0, -3).Value = ws.Parent.Name

                         ' Clear the interim results
                        .Range(.Cells(1, intColNext), .Cells(lr, intColNext)).ClearContents

                         ' Delete the column header copied to the list
                        r.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                        boolWritten = True
                    End If
                End If

                 ' Find the Node column
                intColNode = 0
                On Error Resume Next
                intColNode = WorksheetFunction.Match("node", .Rows(1), 0)
                On Error GoTo 0

                If intColNode > 0 Then
                     ' Only action if there is data in column A
                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(intColNode)) > 1 Then
                        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, intColNode).End(xlUp).Row

                         ' Copy unique values from column A to the 'Unique data' sheet, and write sheet & file details (if not already written)
                        .Range(.Cells(1, intColNode), .Cells(lr, intColNode)).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , y, True
                        If Not boolWritten Then
                            y.Offset(0, -1).Value = ws.Name
                            y.Offset(0, -2).Value = ws.Parent.Name
                        End If

                         ' Delete the column header copied to the list
                        y.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                    End If
                End If

         ' Identify the next row, based on the most rows used in columns C & D
                lngLastNode = wksSummary.Cells(wksSummary.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
                lngLastScen = wksSummary.Cells(wksSummary.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
                lngNextRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(lngLastNode, lngLastScen) + 1
                If (lngNextRow - lngStartRow) > 1 Then



                     ' Fill down the workbook and sheet names
                    z.Resize(lngNextRow - lngStartRow, 2).FillDown
                    If (lngNextRow - lngLastNode) > 1 Then
                         ' Fill down the last Node value
                        wksSummary.Range(wksSummary.Cells(lngLastNode, 3), wksSummary.Cells(lngNextRow - 1, 3)).FillDown
                    End If
                    If (lngNextRow - lngLastScen) > 1 Then
                         ' Fill down the last Scenario value
                        wksSummary.Range(wksSummary.Cells(lngLastScen, 4), wksSummary.Cells(lngNextRow - 1, 4)).FillDown
                    End If
                End If



                Set y = wksSummary.Cells(lngNextRow, 3)
                Set r = y.Offset(0, 1)
                Set z = y.Offset(0, -2)
                lngStartRow = y.Row
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
wb.Close savechanges:=False 'close the workbook do not save
Set wb = Nothing 'release the object
End If

Next 'End of the fileNames loop
Set fileNames = Nothing

 ' Autofit column widths of the report
wksSummary.Range("A1:D1").EntireColumn.AutoFit

' Reset system settings

With Application
   .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   .ScreenUpdating = True
   .Visible = True
End With
End Sub
```

Is there a code that can take the files skipped and put the file names skipped into a new sheet within the active workbook?

EDIT~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

With Katz Fix, also have added "Skipped" to my workbook manually:

```
Sub Katz()
'includes filling down

Dim wb As Workbook, fileNames As Object, errCheck As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wks As Worksheet, wksSummary As Worksheet
    Dim y As Range, intRow As Long, i As Integer
    Dim r As Range, lr As Long, myrg As Range, z As Range
    Dim boolWritten As Boolean, lngNextRow As Long
    Dim intColNode As Integer, intColScenario As Integer
    Dim intColNext As Integer, lngStartRow As Long

    Dim lngLastNode As Long, lngLastScen As Long


    'Compile skipped files
    Dim wksSkipped As Worksheet
    Set wksSkipped = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Skipped")

     ' Turn off screen updating and automatic calculation
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

     ' Create a new worksheet, if required
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wksSummary = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unique data")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wksSummary Is Nothing Then
        Set wksSummary = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
        wksSummary.Name = "Unique data"
    End If

     ' Set the initial output range, and assign column headers
    With wksSummary
        Set y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Set r = y.Offset(0, 1)
        Set z = y.Offset(0, -2)
        lngStartRow = y.Row
        .Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("File Name", "Sheet Name", "Node Name", "Scenario Name")
    End With

'get user input for files to search
Set fileNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
errCheck = UserInput.FileDialogDictionary(fileNames)
If errCheck Then
   Exit Sub
End If
'''
For Each Key In fileNames 'loop through the dictionary




On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileNames(Key))
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wb = Nothing    ' or set a boolean error flag
End If
On Error GoTo 0    ' or your custom error handler

If wb Is Nothing Then
wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = wb.Name
Else
    Debug.Print "Successfully loaded " & fileNames(Key)
    wb.Application.Visible = False 'make it not visible
    ' more working with wb



 ' Check each sheet in turn
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
             ' Only action the sheet if it's not the 'Unique data' sheet
            If .Name <> wksSummary.Name Then
                boolWritten = False

                 ' Find the Scenario column
                intColScenario = 0
                On Error Resume Next
                intColScenario = WorksheetFunction.Match("scenarioName", .Rows(1), 0)
                On Error GoTo 0

                If intColScenario > 0 Then
                     ' Only action if there is data in column E
                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(intColScenario)) > 1 Then
                         ' Find the next free column, in which the extract formula will be placed
                        intColNext = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

                         ' Assign formulas to the next free column to identify the scenario name to the left of the first _ character
                        .Cells(1, intColNext).Value = "Test"
                        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, intColScenario).End(xlUp).Row
                        Set myrg = .Range(.Cells(2, intColNext), .Cells(lr, intColNext))
                        With myrg
                            .ClearContents
                            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(LEFT(RC" & intColScenario & ",FIND(INDEX({""+"",""-"",""_"",""$"",""%""},1,MATCH(1,--(ISNUMBER(FIND({""+"",""-"",""_"",""$"",""%""},RC" & _
                            intColScenario & "))),0)), RC" & intColScenario & ")-1), RC" & intColScenario & ")"
                            .Value = .Value
                        End With

                         ' Copy unique values from the formula column to the 'Unique data' sheet, and write sheet & file details
                        .Range(.Cells(1, intColNext), .Cells(lr, intColNext)).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , r, True
                        r.Offset(0, -2).Value = ws.Name
                        r.Offset(0, -3).Value = ws.Parent.Name

                         ' Clear the interim results
                        .Range(.Cells(1, intColNext), .Cells(lr, intColNext)).ClearContents

                         ' Delete the column header copied to the list
                        r.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                        boolWritten = True
                    End If
                End If

                 ' Find the Node column
                intColNode = 0
                On Error Resume Next
                intColNode = WorksheetFunction.Match("node", .Rows(1), 0)
                On Error GoTo 0

                If intColNode > 0 Then
                     ' Only action if there is data in column A
                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(intColNode)) > 1 Then
                        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, intColNode).End(xlUp).Row

                         ' Copy unique values from column A to the 'Unique data' sheet, and write sheet & file details (if not already written)
                        .Range(.Cells(1, intColNode), .Cells(lr, intColNode)).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , y, True
                        If Not boolWritten Then
                            y.Offset(0, -1).Value = ws.Name
                            y.Offset(0, -2).Value = ws.Parent.Name
                        End If

                         ' Delete the column header copied to the list
                        y.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                    End If
                End If

         ' Identify the next row, based on the most rows used in columns C & D
                lngLastNode = wksSummary.Cells(wksSummary.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
                lngLastScen = wksSummary.Cells(wksSummary.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
                lngNextRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(lngLastNode, lngLastScen) + 1
                If (lngNextRow - lngStartRow) > 1 Then



                     ' Fill down the workbook and sheet names
                    z.Resize(lngNextRow - lngStartRow, 2).FillDown
                    If (lngNextRow - lngLastNode) > 1 Then
                         ' Fill down the last Node value
                        wksSummary.Range(wksSummary.Cells(lngLastNode, 3), wksSummary.Cells(lngNextRow - 1, 3)).FillDown
                    End If
                    If (lngNextRow - lngLastScen) > 1 Then
                         ' Fill down the last Scenario value
                        wksSummary.Range(wksSummary.Cells(lngLastScen, 4), wksSummary.Cells(lngNextRow - 1, 4)).FillDown
                    End If
                End If



                Set y = wksSummary.Cells(lngNextRow, 3)
                Set r = y.Offset(0, 1)
                Set z = y.Offset(0, -2)
                lngStartRow = y.Row
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
wb.Close savechanges:=False 'close the workbook do not save
Set wb = Nothing 'release the object
End If

Next 'End of the fileNames loop
Set fileNames = Nothing

 ' Autofit column widths of the report
wksSummary.Range("A1:D1").EntireColumn.AutoFit

' Reset system settings
With Application
   .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   .ScreenUpdating = True
   .Visible = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. You'll generally find that posting your code is the best bet, so that's certainly recommended. Are you error trapping the files it skips? Or is it just ignoring these?

Comment: Yes, if you post you code we can help you find what is going on.

Comment: @Trum, It just skips them, editing original post now.

Comment: If you want the skipped files to be listed on a separate sheet why don't you just do so instead of dumping the error to the direct window using `Debug.Print "Error when loading " & fileNames(Key)`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Ralph , I was using the error direct window to check which files were unreadable, i forgot to take this out. Do you know what I can add to this macro to put them into a new sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right you would like to write the filenames with are unreadable into a new `worksheet`. If so try this quick and dirty:

Add manually a new `worksheet` to your mainfile, e.g. "Skipped" and
declare it at the beginning:

`Dim wksSkipped As Worksheet`

`Set wksSkipped = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Skipped")`

Replace this

```
If wb Is Nothing Then
Debug.Print "Error when loading " & fileNames(Key)
```

with this

```
If wb Is Nothing Then
wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = wb.Name
```

If your workbook is unreadable it looks at the next free cell in column A at the new sheet and writes down the filename of the unreadable file.

Comment: Hi Katz, thanks for this! but I am getting an error, probably on my part. 'Object Variable or block variable not set' , debugging gets `wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = wb.Name`

Comment: I edited my question to include ur suggestion to show what I did.

Comment: In my test it run all fine. Didn't have the function for `FileDialogDictionary`. But try `wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = fileNames(Key)` instead of `= wb.Name`

Comment: This seems to work, ill do some more testing and reply in an hour

Comment: do you recommend this quick and dirty way? Or should I have the sheet created in my code?

Comment: @Ladiesman191 if it works as needed then everything is fine :) if so feel free to mark my solution as your answer or have you still problems?